# Bootstrap - Remove white line on right side of table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a website made using Bootstrap v3.3.7.

As you can see from the image below, there is a small white line on the right hand side of the panel, at the bottom. It doesnt stretch the whole way up the right side of the panel, on where the table is, so I assume it is something to do with the table.

[Example of the white line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ6aj.png)

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-custom premium">Hosting service name here</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p>A small description of the hosting company here, only plain text, make length of 255 characters.</p>
          <img src="banner.png" class="img-responsive" style="display: block; margin: auto"/>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th><i class="fa fa-internet-explorer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Website</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i> Price of GB/month</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-signal" aria-hidden="true"></i> Uptime</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a>www.website.com</a></td>
            <td>£0.05</td>
            <td>99%</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is my custom CSS**

```
   html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #1F2022 !important;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', serif !important;
}

a {
  color: #B24628 !important;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: white !important;
}

.navbar-custom {
  background: #42424B !important;
  border-color: #42424B !important;
}

.navbar-custom a {
  color: white !important;
}

.active a {
  background: #B24628 !important;
}

.custom-div {
  background: #42424B !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background: #42424B !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background: #B24628 !important;
}

.panel-custom {
  background: #42424B !important;
  border-color: #42424B !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.panel{
  border: none !important;
}

.panel-body, table, tr, td{
  background: #969896 !important;
  border: none !important;
}

td, th {
  text-align: center !important;
}

table { table-layout: fixed !important; }
td { width: 33% !important; }

hr {
  border-color: #42424B !important;
}

.img-pad {
  padding-bottom: 8px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn {
  background: #B24628 !important;
  border-color: #913218 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.footer {
  background: #42424B !important;
  color: white !important;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer a {
  color: #B24628 !important;
}

.footer p {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border: none !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border: none !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background: #B24628 !important;
}

.navbar-form {
  border: none !important;
}

.navbar-default :last-child {
  border-bottom: 0!important;
}

* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

footer { background-color:#42424B; min-height:350px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
.footerleft { margin-top:50px; padding:0 36px; }
.logofooter { margin-bottom:10px; font-size:25px; color:#fff; font-weight:700;}

.footerleft p { color:#fff; font-size:12px !important; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; margin-bottom:15px;}
.footerleft p i { width:20px; color:#999;}


.paddingtop-bottom {  margin-top:50px;}
.footer-ul { list-style-type:none;  padding-left:0px; margin-left:2px;}
.footer-ul li { line-height:29px; font-size:12px;}
.footer-ul li a { color:#a0a3a4; transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s; }
.footer-ul i { margin-right:10px;}
.footer-ul li a:hover {transition: color 0.2s linear 0s, background 0.2s linear 0s; color:#ff670f; }

.social:hover {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 }




 .icon-ul { list-style-type:none !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
 .icon-ul li { line-height:75px; width:100%; float:left;}
 .icon { float:left; margin-right:5px;}


 .copyright { min-height:40px; background-color:#42424B;}
 .copyright p { text-align:left; color:#FFF; padding:10px 0; margin-bottom:0px;}
 .heading7 { font-size:21px; font-weight:700; color:#d9d6d6; margin-bottom:22px;}
 .post p { font-size:12px; color:#FFF; line-height:20px;}
 .post p span { display:block; color:#8f8f8f;}
 .bottom_ul { list-style-type:none; float:right; margin-bottom:0px;}
 .bottom_ul li { float:left; line-height:40px;}
 .bottom_ul li:after { content:"/"; color:#b24628; margin-right:8px; margin-left:8px;}
 .bottom_ul li a { color:#FFF;  font-size:12px;}
/**
 #nav_bar {
   border: 0;
   background-color: #202020;
   border-radius: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   height: 30px;
 }

 .navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
*//

.dark-text {
  color: #333333 !important;
}

.premium {
  background: #B27328 !important;
  border: #B27328 !important;
}

.float-right {
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  .float-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  .float-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}

.bottom_ul a {
  color: white !important;
}
```

*This problem only occurs occasionally* where if I change the width of the web browser, the line goes, but if I make it bigger is comes back. 
Eg. at a width of **1032px**, the line is visible, but at **1034px** it disappears

As you can see, I have tried setting all the borders to none etc. Would the solution be fixed if I downloaded Bootstrap v4 or is it something in my code .Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: white;
}` Maybe there is the problem...

Comment: I tried that, the problem still exists unfortunately